# Can I use the Minecraft tag to draw more attention to a Minecraft mod related issue?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have posted [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/254981/100734) on a mod related issue on the main site. But I did not put the [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) tag in the tags because I thought it was non necessary.

Is this thought good or can I use the tag to draw more attention?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not necessarily going to draw more attention - the tags are more for sorting than anything else. Use the tags that fit best - if you are specifically asking about a mod etc. that we already have a tag for, use that instead of the plain Minecraft tag.

Comment: I thought the policy was to always use the basegame tag, in addition to the tag for the specific mod if relevant.

Comment: @Arperum Entirely possible. But my point still stands - adding it likely isn't going to increase the attention on the question.

Comment: That's true. It might be easier to find through google later on though. People don't always add the mod to the question they are searching. I know I don't do it half the time anyway.

Comment: It definitely seems to me like it would draw more attention. If you have a tag favorited, it highlights the question in the list. I often just scan right past ones that aren't highlighted. If someone has minecraft as one of their favorite tags, then tagging it will make them more likely to notice it, leading to it getting more attention.